# How to prevent SVN from allowing commit if a certain #define is enabled?

Tags: c, svn, c-preprocessor

I use `#define` macros to enable/disable automated testing in my code.  For example, I may use the following line to enable an automated test:

```
#define FEATURE_AUTOMATED_TEST
```

When I commit the code I want this test disabled, so I just comment it out:

```
//#define FEATURE_AUTOMATED_TEST
```

(Normally I don't use C++-style comments in C code but for this stuff it's terribly convenient.)

Unfortunately, sometimes I (or others) accidentally leave the macros enabled on SVN commit, requiring a subsequent SVN commit to fix the problem.  I know I could use some form of `#warning` macro to help prevent this but I'm looking for a better solution.  Something where SVN would go "Um hell no man, you can't check it in like that because you have `FEATURE_AUTOMATED_TEST` enabled. Dumbass."

Any ideas?  I'm completely willing to change how I enable/disable the test sections... it doesn't have to use a `#define` but it does have to exclude any disabled test code at compile time.

Comment: You might do better to have `make test` (or `configure`, or whatever) add the definition conditionally.  Then you don't need to modify your source to enable/disable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [a subversion pre-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html) that:

`grep -l '^#define.*FEATURE_AUTOMATED_TEST'`

for the presence of the macro. You would abort the commit if the exit code of the above command is different than `0`.

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  Might be complicated since we use the same SVN repositories cross-platform (Linux and Windows) so any solution would have to work for both.  I suppose I could just tell the Windows users that they had to install grep and put it on their path.  :)